# Observe property changes of all objects in SwiftData

Tags: swift, core-data, swift-data

In Core Data you can do something like this to observe property changes of all objects of a type:

```swift
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default
    .publisher(for: .NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange)
) { notif in
    guard let userInfo = notif.userInfo else { return }
    let updatedItems: [Item] = (userInfo[NSUpdatedObjectsKey] as?
                                Set<NSManagedObject> ?? [])
        .compactMap{$0 as? Item}
    let becameActive = updatedItems.filter{ (item: Item) -> Bool in
        guard let activeBefore = item
            .changedValuesForCurrentEvent()[#keyPath(Item.active)]
            as? Bool else { return false }
        return !activeBefore && item.active
    }
}
```

How to achieve that in SwiftData? The event still fires but `compactMap{$0 as? Item}` always returns nil. I guess that's because in SwiftData `Item` is a PersistentModel, not a NSManagedObject subclass. Extra points for a cleaner solution.

Comment: The type in `userInfo[NSUpdatedObjectsKey]` is `Set<AnyPersistentObject>` but unfortunately this `AnyPersistentObject` is a private type so we can't use it in our code. And since the SwiftData native notifications `willSave` and `didSave` isn't working yet I don't think using notifications is a way forward currently.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks. `userInfo[NSUpdatedObjectsKey] as! Set<NSManagedObject>` works for me even with SwiftData but is not very useful without further casting.

Comment: Yes right now this isn't very useful. My conclusion from testing different SwiftData and Core Data notifications yesterday is that I will not bother with notifications in my project until the native willSave and didSave notifications will start to work.